# Book tickets for connecting trains

Tags: india, indian-railways

I want to book tickets from Ahmedabad to Boisar in train Jamnagar-Bandra Intercity. But I am not getting that option to book from irctc.co.in. I know this same train goes to boisar and also know that engine and some coaches are added/removed from surat. Thats not the point. Question is how to book the ticket in one go so to get the same seat.

Need an urgent solution want to book for day after tomorrow.

Comment: if not irctc, try third party websites like MakeMyTrip, or Cleartrip?

Comment: It seems they are two distinct trains [22960](http://indiarailinfo.com/train/-train-jamnagar-surat-intercity-express-22960/801/1662/64) and [12936](http://indiarailinfo.com/train/-train-jamnagar-surat-intercity-express-22960/801/1662/64). The best you can do on IRCTC is to book them separately and choose CC or FC (for which there are only two coaches). Otherwise you can go to a booking window and ask the clerk to book a single ticket for entire journey (aka through ticket) which should be cheaper than two separate tickets and he _may_ be able to allocate the same seat.